# Link events to specific bootstrap carousel slides

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to trigger specific events for each slide in my Bootstrap carousel. How do I read which slide is current, and trigger events accordingly? Existing code is keeping count separately from the carousel which is too sloppy. No native functionality for this that I see, please help.

Comment: So was my answer helpfull or not ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code you provided doesn't allow me to trigger on a specific slide, just on every slide.

Comment: What do you mean by, trigger on a specific slide? Because the code that i ve writter triggers every time the slide is changing, but inside that trigger you can check if the slide is the one you need to trigger the event, or if not, you wont do anything. What do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    //here you should add your code
})
```

- **slide.bs.carouse** - This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
- **slid.bs.carousel**- This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

For more information [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage)